# Google Sheet Macro Error "Exception: Invalid Argument"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table

I am currently trying to create a series of pivot tables and filtered views within a macro, but after my first pivot I get Exception: Invalid Argument error.  This is my first attempt at making macros in google sheets.  I have listed my code below from the Apps Script Recorded Macros area.  I ran debug and the arrow points to where the error occurs.

*Update: the line of the error is where I reference the first pivot sheet to put the second pivot beside that sheet(along with 3 more you don't see).  How do I reference a sheet and create Pivot tables on the same sheet with a macro?

````
function Test1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D14').activate();
  var sourceData = spreadsheet.getRange('A1:CJ8007');
  spreadsheet.insertSheet(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getIndex() + 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setHiddenGridlines(true);
  var pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  var pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(61);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  var pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(1, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.COUNTA);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(61);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Report'), true);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Pivot Table 10'), true);<--
  spreadsheet.getRange('D1').activate();
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('D1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('D1').createPivotTable(sourceData);```
````

Comment: I thought that the error message of `Exception: Invalid Argument error` might be that the sheet of `Pivot Table 10` is not existing in the active Spreadsheet. So, how about confirming this again?

Comment: When testing macros the sheet and pivot count go up.  Is there a way to reset the counter?  This will be ran on a hourly/daily basis.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor Engilsh skill. From your replying of `When testing macros the sheet and pivot count go up. Is there a way to reset the counter? This will be ran on a hourly/daily basis.`, I had thought that you might have wanted to know the reason for your issue of `Exception: Invalid Argument error` and remove the issue.

Comment: I think I see the issue.  When I create the second pivot table(and others) I build them onto the same page as the first, so I am referencing the original.  The next line shows that I am assigning that pivot table to D1 of the original pivot sheet(beside the first).  If I remove the line as suggested, it will reference the data page instead of the pivot, and this will lead to my original data being deleted.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I'm worried that I couldn't correctly understand your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to support you. So I would like to try to understand your question. When I could correctly understand your question, I would like to try to think of a solution. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

- Running this code on my end and I've noticed that [getsheetbynamename(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) returns `null` if that Sheet name doesn't exist. Subsequently if you call [spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheet, restoreSelection)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setactivesheetsheet,-restoreselection) passing `sheet` as `null`, the same exception `Exception: Invalid Argument` was returned to me.
- Make sure that the Sheets named `Report` and `Pivot Table 10` exist within the spreadsheet before calling `setActiveSheet(sheet, restoreSelection)`.
- Additionally, given that the script depends on the Sheet data, it'd greatly help to have a sample Sheet with sample data for a better understanding with your script intentions for the troubleshooting.

Comment: If you want to replicate what I am trying to accomplish, just create several pivot tables on one sheet using a macro.  Let me know if you are able to do this successfully, and if so what steps did you take?

Comment: The code above runs on my end if I create the worksheets 'Report' and 'Pivot Table 10' before running it. That's because the exception is caused by `setActiveSheet()` not being able to run with an invalid argument (like a non-existent worksheet). Perhaps, I'm not understanding your intention on the code. Can you share more details on it?

Comment: My intention is to create several pivot tables on one sheet using a Macro.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this can be achieved. However without further context it is hard to help you achieve that. Can you share more details on how is it failing?

Comment: When you call on the sheet to be used in the macro it fails.  This is due to Google sheets not resetting its sheet count.  For example, if you create a macro and it calls on sheet 1 it will fail, because in the macro it will be sheet 2, and this makes it impossible to create more than one pivot table on a single sheet.